# Multiple custom post type use the same template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have three custom post type use the same template:

```
// Custom posttype Photos
$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Photos', 'Post Type General Name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Photos', 'Post Type Singular Name'),
    'menu_name' => __('Photos'),
    'parent_item_colon' => __('Photos:'),
    'all_items' => __('All Items'),
    'view_item' => __('View Item'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Event'),
    'add_new' => __('Add New'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Item'),
    'update_item' => __('Update Item'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Item'),
    'not_found' => __('Not found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Not found in Trash'),
);
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields',),
    'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'photos'),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
    'menu_position' => 10,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-image',
    'can_export' => true,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
);
register_post_type('photos', $args);

// Custom posttype Events
$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Events', 'Post Type General Name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Events', 'Post Type Singular Name'),
    'menu_name' => __('Events'),
    'parent_item_colon' => __('Events:'),
    'all_items' => __('All Items'),
    'view_item' => __('View Item'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Event'),
    'add_new' => __('Add New'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Item'),
    'update_item' => __('Update Item'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Item'),
    'not_found' => __('Not found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Not found in Trash'),
);
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields',),
    'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => __('events')),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
    'menu_position' => 10,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-images-alt2',
    'can_export' => true,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
);
register_post_type('events', $args);

// Custom Courses

    $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Courses', 'Post Type General Name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Courses', 'Post Type Singular Name'),
    'menu_name' => __('Courses'),
    'parent_item_colon' => __('Courses:'),
    'all_items' => __('All Items'),
    'view_item' => __('View Item'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Item'),
    'add_new' => __('Add New'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Item'),
    'update_item' => __('Update Item'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Item'),
    'not_found' => __('Not found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Not found in Trash'),
);
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields',),
    'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'courses'),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
    'menu_position' => 10,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-learn-more',
    'can_export' => true,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
);
register_post_type('courses', $args);
```

I need 3 pages (or archive/taxonomy?): Events show all post events, Page Courses show all post courses, Page Photos show all post photos (They use the same front-end with left sidebar(have function search) and right content)

Currently I use template Left Sibar for 3 pages Events, courses, photos:

```
/*
* Template Name: Left Sidebar
*/
```

I wanna show Name of post type in each page and get all posts of post type. Ex:

- Page events: Show string 'Event listing' and all Event
- Page courses: Show string 'Courses listing' and all Courses
- Page Photos: Show string 'Photos listing' and all Photos

But this template cannot get post type info :(

Another way, i use hierachy wordpress for custom post type:

- Post type events: archive-events.php
- Post type photos: archive-photos.php
- Post type courses: archive-courses.php

Why 'http://mydomain.local/events/' is not found? (events is slug of post type Events). The others same.

Any ideas for this issue?

If you need more info, plz comment. And sorry for my bad english ^^

Comment: How you are getting post type info in template ??

Comment: have you used `global $post_type` there ?

Comment: @Mit Can you please make sure to mark the question resolved? This tidies up the question queue and gives your answerer that sweet sweet reputation.

Comment: Yes, this question was resolved. Thank everyone ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In every single `$args` array you've set `has_archive` to false. This should be set to 'true'. That alone will get you well on your way. The domain http://mydomain.local/events/ should then work. Check out the documentation for 'has_archive' at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type for confirmation.

This guide: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-post-types-archive-page-in-wordpress/ should help you too.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly i want. Thank so much!!

Comment: No worries. Can you please make sure to mark the question resolved? This tidies up the question queue and gives your answerer that sweet sweet reputation.

Comment: I have a problem, with taxonomy of post type Events:
Post Type permalink: mydomain.local/events work good with archive-events.php
Taxonomy of Post type: mydomain.local/type-events is not found. How to fix this issue?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. I'd recommend making a new question with more detail

Comment: Okay, i will. Thank you again!